# Sorting an Array of Dictionaries with multiple criteria in Swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I have an array of dictionaries and my dictionary is type [String:AnyObject]. Here is some data:

```
[{
    name = Joe;
    score = 50;
    favorite = Phone;
    startDate = "2015-10-15";
    startingTime = "2015-10-15 19:00:00 +0000";
    finished = "<null>";
}, {
    name = Mark;
    score = 60;
    favorite = Phone;
    startDate = "2015-10-16”;
    startingTime = "2015-10-16 19:00:00 +0000";
    finished = "<null>";
}, {
    name = Joe;
    score = 30;
    favorite = Phone;
    startDate = "2015-10-15";
    startingTime = "2015-10-15 19:00:00 +0000";
    finished = "<null>";
}]
```

What I want is to be able to sort these first by name, then by startingTime, then if those both match then by score (I have score stored as a string though).

I know this is terribly wrong but I typed in:

```
test.sort({ $0.name! < $1.name! })
```

That gave me an error "Cannot invoke 'sort' with an argument list of type '((_, _) -> _)'."

Can anyone shed some light as to how to do this sort?

** Updated to have code from the view controller with the answer

```
    import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        var allArray = [AnyObject]()
        var array = [String:AnyObject]()

        array["name"] = "Joe"
        array["score"] = 50 as Int
        array["favorite"] = "Phone"
        array["startDate"] = "2015-10-15"
        let date = NSDate()
        array["date"] = date
        array["finished"] = nil
        allArray.append(array)

        array["name"] = "Mark"
        array["score"] = 60 as Int
        array["favorite"] = "Phone"
        array["startDate"] = "2015-10-16"
        array["date"] = date
        array["finished"] = nil
        allArray.append(array)

        array["name"] = "Joe"
        array["score"] = 30 as Int
        array["favorite"] = "Phone"
        array["startDate"] = "2015-10-15"
        array["date"] = date
        array["finished"] = nil
        allArray.append(array)
        println(allArray)

        allArray.sort {
            if let name0 = $0["name"] as? String, name1 = $1["name"] as? String
                where name0 != name1 {
                    return name0 < name1
            }

            // You said 'startingTime' in your question your code showed 'date'
            if let date0 = $0["date"] as? NSDate, date1 = $1["date"] as? NSDate
                where date0.timeIntervalSince1970 != date1.timeIntervalSince1970 {
                    return date0.timeIntervalSince1970 < date1.timeIntervalSince1970
            }

            // You have 'score' as String. I think you would want a numeric type instead
            return ($0["score"] as! Int) < ($1["score"] as! Int)
        }

        println(allArray)

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

Thanks!

Comment: your data looks like a weird kind of JSON that uses equals and semicolon separators and isn't quoting strings.  maybe fix that first

Comment: @spirographer that would be NSDictionary

Comment: @jbandes It's not any syntax I recognize.  See my answer below for syntax that compiles.

Comment: @Joe it looks like your code still doesn't compile in the format you put above, I'm making a couple of changes to my answer to match your formatting, please check it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to add my solution to the already crowded answers because none of the existing one look satisfactory to me.

```
// allArray is as initiated in your viewDidLoad method

let sortedArray = allArray.sort {
    if let name0 = $0["name"] as? String, name1 = $1["name"] as? String
        where name0 != name1 {
            return name0 < name1
    }

    // You said 'startingTime' in your question but your code showed 'date'
    if let date0 = $0["date"] as? NSDate, date1 = $1["date"] as? NSDate
        where date0.timeIntervalSince1970 != date1.timeIntervalSince1970 {
            return date0.timeIntervalSince1970 < date1.timeIntervalSince1970
    }

    // You have 'score' as String. I think you would want a numeric type instead
    return ($0["score"] as! Int) < ($1["score"] as! Int)
}
```

The code is riddled with casts because you use `AnyObject` as the value type.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I took our the let sortedArray part because it wouldn't assign but I didn't need it anyway as I just needed the allArray sorted. I will update the code in the question.

Answer (score 2):

Try being more explicit with the closure parameters if the compiler gets weird like that.

This sort method seems to work for me.

```
arr = arr.sort { a, b in
    if a["name"] == b["name"] {
        if a["startingTime"] == b["startingTime"] {
            return a["score"] > b["score"]
        }
        return a["startingTime"] > b["startingTime"]
    } else {
        return a["name"] > b["name"]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this works, the guard is just so I don't have to deal with unwrapping in the comparisons (I'm loving guard because of this, makes the code cleaner IMO)

```
let test : [[String:AnyObject]] = [["name":"joe", "time":1, "score":5], ["name":"joe", "time":1, "score":3], ["name":"joe", "time":1, "score":7]]

let sorted = test.sort{
    guard let name = $0["name"] as? String,
    let time = $0["time"] as? Int,
    let score = $0["score"] as? Int,
    let name1 = $1["name"] as? String,
    let time1 = $1["time"] as? Int,
    let score1 = $1["score"] as? Int else{
            //unwrapping failed, sort is going to be bad
            return false
    }

    if name == name1 {
        if time == time1 {
            return score < score1
        }else {
            return time < time1
        }
    }else {
        return name < name1
    }

}

print(sorted)
```

Comment: I am still using Xcode 6.4 is there any way you could help me convert the syntax? If so that would be helpful

Answer (score 0):

Here are some code fragments that make the given code work better.  First add these to the beginning of your file to make dates comparable.

```
    public func ==(lhs: NSDate, rhs: NSDate) -> Bool {
        return lhs === rhs || lhs.compare(rhs) == .OrderedSame
    }

    public func <(lhs: NSDate, rhs: NSDate) -> Bool {
        return lhs.compare(rhs) == .OrderedAscending
    }

    extension NSDate: Comparable { }
```

Then use the syntax below in your method (this is swift 2):

```
    var allArray = [AnyObject]()
    var array = [String:AnyObject]()

    array["name"] = "Joe"
    array["score"] = "50"
    array["favorite"] = "Phone"
    array["startDate"] = "2015-10-15"
    let date = NSDate()
    array["startingTime"] = date
    array["finished"] = nil
    allArray.append(array)

    array["name"] = "Mark"
    array["score"] = "60"
    array["favorite"] = "Phone"
    array["startDate"] = "2015-10-16"
    array["startingTime"] = date
    array["finished"] = nil
    allArray.append(array)

    array["name"] = "Joe"
    array["score"] = "30"
    array["favorite"] = "Phone"
    array["startDate"] = "2015-10-15"
    array["startingTime"] = date
    array["finished"] = nil
    allArray.append(array)
    print(allArray)

    allArray.sortInPlace { i,j in (i["name"] as! String) < (j["name"] as! String) || (i["startingTime"] as! NSDate) < (j["startingTime"] as! NSDate) }
```

I do prefer if you use syntax like this though.  It is a more swift way of declaring an array of dictionaries.

```
    let xyz = [
        [
            "name" : "Joe",
            "score" : 50,
            "favorite" : "Phone",
            "startDate" : "2015-10-15",
            "startingTime" : "2015-10-15 19:00:00 +0000",
            "finished" : "<null>"
        ], [
            "name" : "Mark",
            "score" : 60,
            "favorite" : "Phone",
            "startDate" : "2015-10-16",
            "startingTime" : "2015-10-16 19:00:00 +0000",
            "finished" : "<null>"
        ], [
            "name" : "Joe",
            "score" : 30,
            "favorite" : "Phone",
            "startDate" : "2015-10-15",
            "startingTime" : "2015-10-15 19:00:00 +0000",
            "finished" : "<null>"
        ]
    ]
    var test = xyz.sort { ($0["name"] as! String) < ($1["name"] as! String) }
```